Calculate sum of series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i a_{i + k}$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$
I'm trying to find closed form of the sum of the following series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\rule{0pt}{5mm}\left(n + 1\right)^{\alpha} + \left(n - 1\right)^{\alpha} - 2n^{\alpha}\right]
\left[\rule{0pt}{5mm}\left(n + 1 + k\right)^{\alpha} + \left(n + k - 1\right)^{\alpha}-
2\left(n + k\right)^{\alpha}\right],
$$
where $\alpha \in \left(0, 2\right), k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I've tried several approaches, tried to represent this sum as integral sum for some function, to make it telescopic, but haven't any success.

Will be very thankful for any help.

When $\alpha\ne1$, why do you think it has a closed form?

@GregMartin I'm not sure it has. Each bracket contains expression which looks similar to numeric schema for second derivative calculation, so it gives me a hope it is closed-form solution. Maybe it does not have, I try to figure out.

Numerical approximations to closed-form expressions often don't themselves have closed forms. I'm pessimistic about this one.

A bunch of mixed polylogarithms are probably involded, since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^kt^n = \mathrm{Li}_{-k}(t)$$

I managed to get to this expression:
$$4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{i,j=1}^\infty{\alpha\choose 2i}{\alpha\choose 2j}n^{\alpha-2i}(n+k)^{\alpha-2j}$$
Is there any way to sum $n^{\alpha-2i}(n+k)^{\alpha-2j}$ over all $n$?
